# Clarification of logical statements AND and OR in a while loop

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

`AND` and `OR` statements behave strangely in a while loop

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

while (a < 3 && b < 3) {
  if (a < 3) {
    a = a + 1
    console.log(a)
    console.log("Ende")
  } else if (b < 3) {
    b = b + 1;
    console.log(b);
  }
}
```

Now, you would expect that a while loop will do its job until both variables reach 3 in an `AND` statement. However that is not the case, it does its job until `a` reaches 3, then stops.

Why?
If you change it to `OR` Operator, it doesn't stop until both variables reach 3.
Once again why?

Comment: Think about it. If `a` is 3 and `b` is 1, how can it be true that both `a` **and** `b` are less than 3?

Comment: What does this have to do with `html`, `css`, and `sapui5`?

Comment: take a minute and think again what AND actually means ;)

Comment: "*it does its job until `a` reaches 3, then stops*" - the `while` loop will continue until the condition inside it is `false`. The condition itself is made of two conditions AND-ed. The first condition is `a < 3` the second `b < 3`. In the beginning they are both `true`, so when you do `true AND true` you get  `true` and the `while` loop executes. With `a = 3` the condition `a < 3` is now `false`. `false AND true` results in `false`.

Comment: If you remove the `else` from your example it behaves as you expect it to

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, i found the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the behavior is mathematically correct. It is unfortunate that the English language can sometimes make `and` and `or` ambiguous.

Consider the condition:

```
a < 3 && b < 3
```

Your intuition in the English language makes you think:

> Now, you would expect that a while loop will do its job until both variables reach 3

But this is wrong. The condition will work as long as both variables are less than 3. This obviously means that if any of the variables reach 3 the condition is false. This is actually true even in English grammar but is muddied by how common usage (which is logically incorrect) of AND and OR interact with lists.

First let's consider the correct usage:

`a < 3 && b < 3` - this means

- Both conditions must be true (the definition of AND)

  - `a` must not reach 3
  - `b` must not reach 3

The truth table is therefore:

```
    a        b        result
 -----------------------------
   < 3      < 3        true
   3++      < 3        false  // AND requires both to be true
   < 3      3++        false  // however OR only requires one to be true
   3++      3++        false
```

Once you write down the truth table for AND you can see why if any of the variable reaches 3 it must stop the loop.

---

Now let's see how English confuses things. I would like to note that strictly speaking English grammar agrees with mathematical definition of AND and OR but common usage is technically wrong even though everyone intuitively understand the meaning (everyone somehow magically ignores logic).

In English, if we have a list where we want everything in the list (like a shopping list) we use `and` to join the list:

```
I want an orange, an apple AND a banana
```

The above sentence requires one to buy all three fruits.

On the other hand, if we have a list of options we join it with an `or`:

```
You can either walk OR drive there
```

Strictly speaking, the actual rule is if you want all parts of the list to be true/to exist then you join it with an AND and if you only need at least one part of the list to be true/exist you join it with an OR. But this is not how English speakers interpret AND and OR. We informally use the previous definition of wanting everything or wanting some of the things.

This subtle difference becomes a major issue when negation is involved (the less than also triggers it). Informally we understand the following:

```
I don't want apples, I don't want oranges AND I don't want bananas
```

as - if there is an apple an orange and a banana then the person above would not be happy. But the correct interpretation would be that the person would not be happy if given an apple even though we have not given him an orange and banana. This is because he wants none of them, he did not say he only does not want all three fruits together but doesn't mind just a banana.

Now let's consider the following:

```
I don't want an apple and an orange.
```

At first sight it looks the same as the sentence above only shorter. However logically there is a difference. In this case the person states that he does not want an apple with an orange but is maybe OK with an apple without an orange.

This similar sounding but radically different meanings of how AND and OR behaves in lists has a name. It actually has a theorem in boolean algebra: It's called [DeMorgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). It is actually obvious but does not seem so at first sight.

It states:

```
( NOT A ) AND ( NOT B ) is the same as NOT ( A OR B )
```

and

```
( NOT A ) OR ( NOT B )  is the same as NOT ( A AND B )
```

This is why sometimes when AND does not work the way you think it does changing it to OR suddenly works.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, i found the solution!